# How long will it take to create Solana RPC node?

Tags: rpc, validator, node, private-node

As we know that it takes a long time to synchronize the data when building an Ether node, I would like to know how long it takes to build a Solana RPC node until it is ready to interact, and is it the same as Ether, which takes a long time to finish synchronizing data? Thank you!